# To Be + Possessive verb

Tags: sentence-construction, passive-voice

Recently read about one grammar rule in English that is *we cannot use is, was and were with possessive verb*

My Active sentence is

This is my property. I owned this property since last 5 years.

Correct passive sentence construction

e.g.    1) This property belonged to me since last 5 years.

```
2) This property owned by me since last 5 years.
```

Whereas if I construct sentence like below sentences does it change the meaning?

My Passive sentence construction

e.g.    1) This property is belonged to me since 5 years.

```
2) This property is owned by be since 5 years.
```

Similarly for past passive construction

```
    1) This property was belonged to me for 5 years.
2) This property was owned by be for 5 years.
```

My question is why we can’t use this as above?
Does it change the meaning of sentence?

Comment: what about "This property has belonged to me since 5 years ago." ?

Comment: or X belongs/belonged to me

Comment: _Belong_ is a verb, and _own_ is a pronoun/adjective. _Was_ does not work with verbs. Verbs use _has_.

Comment: If you want to highlight duration of your ownership, you'd better use past perfect continuous. However, because own and belong are state verbs , you should not use continuous tenses. Ultimately, you can use Present perfect to show the length of the ownership.

Comment: You cannot use *since* with a timespan: *since* is used with a specific point in time to define a timespan stretching from that point to the time you are currently talking about.

Comment: OH, I made a mistake again ! sorry, yep, it must be "for"

Answer (score 1):

The "rule" you refer to is badly formulated.

- It is **not** true that *BE* cannot be used with any of these verbs; most of those which are transitive (that is, they take an object—*own*, *possess*, for instance) can be cast in the passive construction, *BE* + *VERB* <sup>past participle</sup>.

  > <sup>ok</sup>I own this car. → <sup>ok</sup>This car is owned by me, but driven by my son.

  It **is** true, however, that passive constructions with these verbs are pretty rare; in particular, we almost never cast possessive *have* in the passive voice. In the present tense we prefer to employ these verbs in the active voice, because in most circumstances we feel that current ownership is a quality of the owner, not of the thing owned. We're more tolerant of passive constructions in the past tense. Ownership 'feels' more like a quality of an object when we're speaking of its history:

  > <sup>ok</sup>This grand mansion was once possessed by Lord Derby.
  >   <sup>ok</sup>This car was owned by a little old lady who only drove it to church on Sundays.

  *Belong* is a different matter. *Belong* cannot be cast in the passive voice, because the passive moves the semantic object into the subject role and *belong* is an ***in***transitive—it does not take an object—so there is no object to move.
- It **is** true that that we do not usually use *BE* to cast these verbs in the progressive construction *BE* + *VERB* <sup>present participle</sup>. This is true not just of verbs of possession, but all **stative** verbs: verbs which express an enduring state rather than an event or action.  The primary function of the progressive construction is to "recast" an eventive verb as stative so that we can speak of the verb's action as enduring over time; but there is no need to do this with stative verbs, which have that enduring sense built in to their meaning.

  Possession is a state, not an event, so most verbs of possession are stative. Consequently, they are not usually employed in progressive construction.

  > <sup>∗</sup> I am owning this car.
  >   <sup>∗</sup> Lord Derby was once possessing this grand mansion.

---

<sup>∗</sup>  marks an utterance as unacceptable.